# How can I add a Google Content Attribute (Google Shopping)

Tags: magento-1.9, mage-googleshopping

I am using the following google shopping extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html

This extension works great for me, but I want to add a new google content attribute, because I want to import a special product price for products too. Currently I can't mapping a special price because only the google content attribute "price" is selectable, but I need a seperate attribute for special prices. Hope you can help me :)

[image: Google Content Attributes]

UPDATE: I have changed the config.xml of Google Shopping Extension and now the sale_price is also available for other countries then US. Product Synchronisation works, but I can't see the special price in google merchant center.

```
                    <sale_price translate="name">
                        <name>Sale Price</name>
                        <required>0</required>
                        <!--<country>US</country>-->
                    </sale_price>
                    <sale_price_effective_date_from translate="name">
                        <name>Sale Price Effective From Date</name>
                        <required>0</required>
                        <!--<country>US</country>-->
                    </sale_price_effective_date_from>
                    <sale_price_effective_date_to translate="name">
                        <name>Sale Price Effective To Date</name>
                        <required>0</required>
                        <!--<country>US</country>-->
                    </sale_price_effective_date_to>
```

Comment: I have changed the config.xml of google shopping extension, because sale_price was only available for US, so now I can map the "special price" with "sale_price", but I don't see this special price in google merchant center :(. Any idea?

Comment: did you solve issue?

Comment: Not really, because I can add the sale price also for other countries now, but if I take a look at google merchant center, so it seems that this price won't be transfered or synchronised :(.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party extension. Please contact the provider directly for support.

Comment: this extension is developed by magento

Comment: it seems that this extension from magento itself would not be longer supported

Comment: how to add google category product which is predefined by google