# google shopping feed in magento 2

Tags: magento2, google-product-feeds

was able to create shopping in magento but i am facing 3 issues

```
1> Encoding problem (double UTF8 encoding) in attribute: description
2> Google category product (how to add it as its google predefined )
3> Invalid or missing required attribute: link
```

https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324436?hl=en
Link provided by google for the predefined product category
 Tried with the below link 
[How can I add a Google Content Attribute (Google Shopping)](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46252/how-can-i-add-a-google-content-attribute-google-shopping)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">  
      <channel>  
        <title>Magento Store</title>
        <link>{{ context.store.base_url }}</link>
        <description>Products for Magento Store.</description>
        {% for product in context.products %}
        <item>
          <g:id><![CDATA[{{ product.sku }}]]></g:id>
          <g:sku><![CDATA[{{ product.sku }}]]></g:sku>
          <g:title><![CDATA[{{ product.name  }}]]></g:title>
          <g:price>{{ product.finalPrice }} YEN</g:price>
          <g:condition>new</g:condition>
          <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
          <g:sale_price>{{ product.finalPrice }} YEN</g:sale_price>
          <g:image_link>{{ product.image }}</g:image_link>
          <g:link>{{ product.url }}</g:link>
          <g:product_type><![CDATA[{{ product.category.path }}]]></g:product_type>
          <g:google_product_category><![CDATA[]]></g:google_product_category>
         <g:brand><![CDATA[{{ product.manufacturer }}]]></g:brand>
          <g:description><![CDATA[{{ product.desc_features  }}]]></g:description>  
  <g:gtin><![CDATA[{{ product.gtin }}]]></g:gtin>
          <g:mpn>{{ product.parent.sku }}</g:mpn>
          <g:package_height>{{ product.ts_dimensions_height }}</g:package_height>
          <g:package_length>{{ product.ts_dimensions_length }}</g:package_length>
          <g:package_width>{{ product.ts_dimensions_width }}</g:package_width>
          <g:package_weight>{{ product.weight }} kg</g:package_weight>
        </item>
        {% endfor %}
      </channel>
    </rss>
```